# Who to Render Multiple fetch function in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Multiple fetch res render function , hey I am trying to perform and multiple res render function in ejs but my data is lost is their any fix

```
app.get("/" , function(req,res){
    fetch(`${domain}/popular`)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(datap => {
        res.render('home',{datap : JSON.parse(datap)});})
    fetch(`${domain}/recent-release`)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(datar => {
        res.render('home',{datar : JSON.parse(datar)});})
})
```

i want to make multiple fetch function but the datar is replacing datap

Answer (score 1):

Convert the [function to `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), `await` for the two requests, render only when they're done. (I also took the liberty of using the asynchronous [`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) parser instead of `res.text()` + `JSON.parse`.)

```
app.get("/", async function(req, res) {
  const res1 = await fetch(`${domain}/popular`);
  const datap = await res1.json();
  const res2 = await fetch(`${domain}/recent-release`);
  const datar = await res2.json();
  res.render("home", { datap, datar });
});
```

(A future optimization could be to do the two requests in parallel using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).)